# Bootstrap column offsets with variable sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have the following very simple HTML page layout:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

And the sass

```
.content {
   @include make-sm-column(7);
   @include make-sm-column-push(5);
}

.sidebar {
   @include make-sm-column(5);
   @include make-sm-column-pull(7);
}
```

**The sidebar has to come after the content.**

Is there a way to have the content "pushed" to the right *only* if a sidebar is present?

Comment: This is related to off-canvas, correct?  Assuming that you would apply a class to `.content` when `.sidebar` is active, that adds an appropriate padding.

Comment: Nothing to do with off-canvas. I was just trying to avoid having to use body classes eg `.has-sidebar` / `.no-sidebar` to add or remove the push/pull mixins. Thinking that there's probably some better way to do this with `display:flex` and ordering.